# CakePHP confirmation popup not appearing

Tags: php, javascript, cakephp

When a user clicks a submit button a popup should appear asking them if they wish to submit the selection. I've been adding to the view, and I just noticed that although the form works properly, I no longer receive a popup asking to confirm the selection.

This consists of two tables. An upper one to display info where each row has a checkbox. The bottom table allows you to choose if you want to submit only selected checkboxes, or all of the rows in the table.

```
<table>
    <? 
    echo $this->Form->create(null,array(
                    'onsubmit'=>'return confirm("Are you sure you want to archive?'));
    ?>              
    <th>Order ID</th><th>Order Date</th><th>Order Total</th><th>Status</th><th>View</th><th>Select to Archive</th>
    <?php foreach ($orders as $order): ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $order['Order']['id'];?> </td>
            <td><?php echo $order['Order']['date']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $order['Order']['total'];?> </td>
            <td><?php echo $order['Order']['order_status'];?> </td>
            <td><a href="/orders/details/<?php echo $order['Order']['id']; ?>"/>View Order</a> </td>
            <td><? echo $this->Form->checkbox('archive_value.', array('hiddenField' => false, 'value' => $order['Order']['id'])); ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>    

<table class = "table_order_status">
    <tr>
        <td width="350">
            <?
            echo $this->Form->input('archive_values', array('options' => $archive_options, 'value' => $select_value, 'name' => 'archive'));
            ?>
        </td>
        <td>
            <?
            echo $this->Form->end(__('Submit')); 
            ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in the `onsubmit` option. Look at your quotes. Im guessing this line:

```
'onsubmit'=>'return confirm("Are you sure you want to archive?'));
```

should be:

```
 'onsubmit'=>'return confirm("Are you sure you want to archive?")');
```

Comment: Oh jeez, I wish it wasn't so blatantly obvious! Thank you, how embarrassing.

Comment: No problem. It happens :) If the answered fixed your problem, can you accept it please?

Comment: Don't worry @user2443591, we all do that sometimes! :)